# PHP Tidy 'u'-tag is replaced by 'span'

Tags: php, tidy

Could anyone help to identify the problem with tidy?

Next line:

```
<p><u>Risk Warning</u><br />Please note that...</p>
```

After:

```
$config = array(
            'clean' => true,
            'doctype' => '<!DOCTYPE HTML>',
            'drop-proprietary-attributes' => true,
            'output-xhtml' => true,
            'show-body-only' => true,
            'drop-font-tags' => false,
            'merge-spans' => true,
            'wrap' => '0',
            'ascii-chars' => false,
            'char-encoding' => 'utf8',
            'input-encoding' => 'utf8',
            'output-encoding' => 'utf8'
        );
$tidy = new \tidy();
$tidy->parseString($text, $config, 'utf8');
$tidy->cleanRepair();
echo tidy_get_output($tidy);
```

Is replaced by:

```
<p><span class="c1">Risk Warning</span><br />Please note that...</p>
```

How to prevent 'u'-tag change? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$tidy->cleanRepair(); - is not needed here